# Qt5 Loading .qm translation file

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I'm trying to translate my Qt5.5 application to English. I made .ts file and translated strings -> made English.qm file.
I've placed it in resources:

translations.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/translations">
        <file>Resources/Languages/English.qm</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

When I'm trying to load it, I can't... Could you help me how to do it the right way to load .qm and replace orginal strings by translated from .qm?
One additional question, how to load orginal strings when translation is loaded?

fragment of main.cpp file:

```
QtSingleApplication a(argc, argv);

QTranslator tra;
if (tra.load(":/translations/Resources/Languages/English.qm"))
{
    a.installTranslator(&tra);
}
else 
{
    qWarning() << "File not loaded"
}
```

I always get information "File not loaded".

Comment: Try the path without "*.qm", this at least works in my application: `tra.load(":/translations/Resources/Languages/English"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, tried it myself:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/translations">
        <file>resources/languages/english.qm</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

QApplication a(argc, argv);
QTranslator tra;
if (tra.load(":translations/resources/languages/english.qm")) {
    a.installTranslator(&tra);
    qDebug() << "File loaded";
} else {
    qWarning() << "File not loaded";
}
return a.exec();

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

TRANSLATIONS += resources/languages/english.ts
```

Creation of the ts file:
lupdate Test.pro

Creation of the qm file:
lrealease Test.pro

Comment: Still I get "File not loaded" :(

Comment: ok, when I changed one line:  if (tra.load(":/translations/Resources/Languages/English.qm")), Your code works. One more question, could I remove translator and back to normal strings without restart application?

Comment: QApplication has as function `removeTranslator(QTranslator *translator)` with it you can remove it.  Afterwards you can "retranslate" the application again and all strings should be as they were. It is like changing the language.  That works without a restart, as long as all your text is set in an own function and is called after (un)installing a translator.  In Qt this function is called retranslateUi();

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)